# Deploy many ASP.NET in IIS in Public IP

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2016

I have one VPS window server 2016. I want to host many ASP.NET application in VPS. And access it over Internet. I deployed many site with different port but I only access it by public ip and port 80 (Default Site).

I want to ask how to host many site in one Public IP and different port.
Or many path such as tomcat server (publicip:8080/app1; publicip:8080:app2).

Comment: ASP.NET web apps can be deployed as multiple sites like you did, but they can also be deployed as child applications under the same site. So what you should do is to learn more about ASP.NET and IIS, so as to find the proper ways, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis You should also buy a domain, as nobody would like to memorize IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you. I only deploy ASP.NET API for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish all your sites on port 80 by using a different host header in each site.

Site1.yourdomain.com
Site2.yourdomain.com

Site1.otherdomain.com
Site2.otherdomain.com

All of them can be published in IIS over port 80.

Comment: Oh. I don't have domain. Do have way to using(ex : 33.25.62.123: 81 or 
33.25.62.123/app1 )

Comment: I study ASP.NET API. I want publish to VPS. But I have many ASP.NET App and only 1 VPS. You have any way to do it ?

Comment: You can use different combinations of : IP address + Port + Host header, yo can buy a domain for 5 -10 dollars a year and use any subdomain in each application .